# I get an error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file hola.jar

Tags: java, jar

i am using Linux ubuntu and i have created a java program named hola.java which is the following program code, this program works perfectly

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class hola extends JFrame {

JButton b1 = new JButton("presionar");

 hola(){

  super("Botones");
  setSize(250,250);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  FlowLayout flo=new FlowLayout();
  setLayout(flo);
  add(b1);
  setVisible(true);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
 {


    hola bt = new hola();
   }

}
```

This java program works perfectly when it runs
Now I created a jar file of this program using in command line:

> jar cf hola.jar hola.class

This creates a Jar file named hola.jar

I even wrote Main-Class: hola in the manifest.mf file.

When I try to run this by:

> java -jar hola.jar

I get an error: `An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file hola.jar`

Please tell me how to run jar file so that I get an output :'( , what could be the possible reason that i can not run this program as a jar file, even the program works perfectly using "java hola.java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a java file within a jar file, you don't need to open it. You simply need to ensure your classpath is having the given jar file

If the class is within a package then you can run using

```
java -cp hola.jar package.hola
```

If the class is not in a package then simply use

```
java -cp hola.jar hola
```

If you are not within the directory where hola.jar is located, then you can try following:

- In case of within package

  `java -cp /locationOfJar/hola.jar package.hola`
- or In case of not in package

  `java -cp /locationOfJar/hola.jar hola`

Comment: and what about the mainfest?, does the method of creating a jar file shown above is wrong?, what is the best method of creating a jar file in linux command prompt?

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo If you simply needs to create a jar in linux then you simply needs to do `jar cvf classes.jar *.class`. Though the verbose output doesn't indicate it, the Jar tool automatically adds a manifest file to the JAR archive with path name `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Also refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html for more details

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo If this solved the issue, then you could close this  question by selecting an answer as accepted solution

Comment: root@*******:/******/Documentos/java_examples/hola# jar cvf hola.jar *.class
manifiesto agregado
agregando: hola.class(entrada = 740) (salida = 499)(desinflado 32%)
root@********:/******/Documentos/java_examples/hola# java -cp hola.jar hola i already made it and it is working, thanks

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo If its working then you should close this question, by accepting the answer

Comment: if i want to open it with double click it does not work even if i open the manifest and write Main-Class: hola, not command prompt, it is very hard to manipulate jars

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo Why do you want to open this jar?

Comment: Sorry it is not "open", it is execute the program .jar just with double click using mouse

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo I would recommend to create a separate question for same so that everyone else can also benefit with the answers

Comment: Thank you very much, i will continue trying to creating and executing jar files :(, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @OmarElioTorresCastillo Just found this. Perhaps you need to try this --- http://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click

Answer (score 3):

This error mostly indicates invalid `MANIFEST.MF` file. Perhaps long line, missing final line terminator, accidental empty line in the middle, ... many things can go wrong. Using `-cp` just goes around the problem, but does not fix the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

#### Error can also happen with > 65535 files in the .jar on some OS

I experienced same error message attempting to launch via -jar:

```sh
$ java -jar app.jar
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file: app.jar
```

Root cause is that my sbt-assembly output .jar file contains more than 65535 entries.

```sh
$ zipinfo app.jar |wc -l
65543
```

**Solution:** Short term solution was removal of older dependencies to lower the number of assembled .class files below the 16 bit file count limit.

Long term solution will involve testing Zip64 jvm support on the target OS.  Unsure of why the zip64 auto negotiation isn't occurring automatically.

This issue is reproducible using sbt-assembly 15.0, openjdk version "11.0.8" on MacOSX 10.15.7.

Start of the code review:

```java
package java.util.zip;
...
public
class ZipOutputStream extends DeflaterOutputStream implements ZipConstants {

    /**
     * Whether to use ZIP64 for zip files with more than 64k entries.
     * Until ZIP64 support in zip implementations is ubiquitous, this
     * system property allows the creation of zip files which can be
     * read by legacy zip implementations which tolerate "incorrect"
     * total entry count fields, such as the ones in jdk6, and even
     * some in jdk7.
     */
    private static final boolean inhibitZip64 =
        Boolean.parseBoolean(
            GetPropertyAction.privilegedGetProperty("jdk.util.zip.inhibitZip64"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help people that meet the error nowdays (03/2024):

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file ...
```

This issue occurs while trying to launch a jar with Java version 1.8.0_375 and later versions. Due to a new property (jdk.jar.maxSignatureFileSize) introduced in this version.The default this is set as 8MB(8000000 bytes), however, my signed jar is be around 150MB+ in size.

So add :

```
-Djdk.jar.maxSignatureFileSize=800000000
```